# Django how to sort Datefield by order of Day-month to show birthday list

Tags: python, django, django-models, datefield

I want to accept users birthday and have a page which shows everyone's birthday ignoring which year they were born in Heres my models.py for CustomUser:

```
from datetime import datetime, date

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # First/last name is not a global-friendly pattern
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)
    birth_date = models.DateField(("Birth Date"), default=date.today)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Here is my views.py logic:

```
def birthdaylist(request):
    if(request.user.is_authenticated):

        users=CustomUser.objects.order_by('birth_date')[:]
    # ignore the line below
    #   users= CustomUser.objects.extra(select={'birthmonth':'birth_date'},order_by=['birthmonth'])
        context={
            'users':users
        }
        return render(request,'dashboard/birthdaylist.html',context=context)
    else:
        return redirect('login')
```

Here is my forms.py:

```
import datetime

from bootstrap_datepicker_plus import DatePickerInput
from django import forms

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm


from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'gender', 'security_question', 'answer', 'birth_date', 'resume')
        widgets={
            'birth_date' :DatePickerInput(
                options={
                    'maxDate':str(datetime.datetime.now()),
                    #this needs width positioning
                }
            )
        }
```

I am using bootstrap datepicker plus widget to pick the date. Can someone help me on how do I get the desired result in my views .py? I feel something needs to be added in my order.py if u need me to add anything then comment. PS: I am using Django 2.0.6 version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
users=CustomUser.objects.extra(
      select={
      'month': 'extract (month from birth_date)', 
      'day': 'extract (day from birth_date)'},
       order_by=['month','day']
)
```

---

How about this one?

```
from django.db.models.functions import Extract

users=CustomUser.objects.annotate(
     month=Extract('birth_date','month'),
     day=Extract('birth_date','day')
  ).order_by('month','day')
```

Comment: Exception Type: OperationalError,
Exception Value: no such function: MONTH... THIS IS THE ERROR I AM GETTING.. I am using Django 2.0.6

Comment: Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value: 
near "from": syntax error.. Maybe something is wrong with the syntax